# Config to pass to Asterisk so it rings all extensions starting from "4" when a certain number is dialed

Tags: voip, openwrt, asterisk

Which magic **configuration line in which file should I put so that when a certain number is dialed, all extensions that match some wildcard ring, and a call is transferred to the phone which picks up first**?

Background:

1) I am doing it for home and I am no way an asterisk admin by profession.

2) I have an OpenWRT "PBX" application that installs asterisk 1.8.32.3 with Luci admin pages. Hopefully it doesn't touch some of the asterisk config file so I'm able to tweak it with them

3) I own a D-link DVG-7111s Voip router, attached to my network through its Wan port, FXO goes to the PSTN, and FXS port is connected to a regular phone, which, however, is capable to read CallerID.

4) There is a number of softphones registered, and one hard sip phone registered in this asterisk. All their numbers start from 4.

So all this is needed to ring all registered phones when a call comes to D-Link's FXO port. Strangely there is no obvious config for this neither in OpenWRT PBX, nor in D-link. The latter allows me to register FXS port as a sip phone, it has a number 400. The FXO is also registered as 399.

There is a function called "Hot Line", which dials one number when a call comes to FXO. It works.

I think I need to create a dummy number like 398, and then teach Asterisk to ring all 4?? phones when someone calls to this number.

Hope it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad.

You should use extensions.conf file, sip.conf(or other depend of your trunk type), ringgroups or queues.conf

For more info can recommend you read Orelly's "The future of telephony" book

Comment: How trunk type affects anything dialed internally? Discard the broad background, the question is pretty exact. Someone from some extension (say, 399) dials number 402. I decide to use queues.conf from your list of options. What should I put there to that all extensions that start from 4 ring?

Comment: Anything in asterisk,including extensions and trunks use channel driver, config for channel driver depend of protocol/type.

Comment: Your questions still too broad. Can recommend you read book suggested or start from wiki. https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Building+Queues

Comment: I have no idea about channel drivers. Asterisk runs in OpenWRT right away, I am able to make internal calls and I am able to register it at an external sip server in the internets for successful outbound calls without me becoming an asterisk guru. Thanks for your advice to read a book to configure one little function that is not controlled by an OpenWRT web-based admin page. I will still wait for exact advice, probably based on assumptions about my default channel/driver/etc installation or preceded by additional questions on my clearly non-unique vanilla setup.

Comment: So you channel driver is chan_sip or chan_pjsip. Sorry, you are askign question already writed everywhere, in every book.

Comment: There are no way give you exact advise except link i send you.

Comment: I don't think I have pjsip as they write it was introduced in ver 12 while I have 1.8. I don't have queues.conf. Really too much to investigate (including confusing terminology like trunks, dial plans, users vs extensions vs agents etc) for a simple config or to learn that it is impossible. Based on what I've read I guess it is impossible to ring extensions selected by wildcard "4??". I don't want to list all extensions in some "rule". I will have to read and experiment for too long. So I worded the question very simply for a specialist to just answer.

Comment: it is imposible to do ring all 4xx by one regexp. You have write exactly which one you want be called. Your question have no sense.

Comment: OK, thanks. Will find another way of achieving what I want